# Proc macro "main" not expanded + Rust-analyzer not spawning server

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros, rust-analyzer

I join these two questions in one, as they maybe are related. A few days ago, I started having this error in the [#actix_rt::main] line, before the main function:

```
proc macro `main` not expanded: cannot find proc-macro server in sysroot `C:\Users\zerok\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`
```

At the same time, in VSCode my rust-analyzer extension started failing. I uninstalled it, restarted VSCode, and reinstalled. It keeps giving the same error over and over:

```
Failed to spawn one or more proc-macro servers.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soon after posting the question, I finally found out how to install the toolchain, which seems to have fixed both errors:

```
rustup toolchain install stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
```

After that, I clicked on the `rust-analyzer` box on the bottom of VSCode, clicked in "Restart Server", and everything worked after the command completion.

Comment: Good to know: proc macro expansion is no longer supported in toolchains older than 1.64 - you can check your toolchain version using `rustc -V`. 
See [this discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/14554#issuecomment-1505626832)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on Mac, this my error

```
Failed to spawn one or more proc-macro servers.

- cannot find proc-macro-srv, the workspace 
`/Users/xxxx/vscode/rust/guessing_game` is missing a sysroot

Failed to find sysroot for Cargo.toml file 
/Users/xxxx/vscode/rust/guessing_game/Cargo.toml. Is rust-src installed? 
can't load standard library from sysroot

/Users/xxxx/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin

(discovered via `rustc --print sysroot`)

try installing the Rust source the same way you installed rustc
```

here's my fix

```
# install rust-src
sudo rustup component add rust-src
```

[More information](https://github.com/zhangwt-cn/notes/issues/8)

Answer (score 2):

My problem was related to a setting on VS Code

"rust-analyzer.cargo.sysroot": "discover"

Don't know how but the above setting was set to null. The default is "discover".

Comment: This was the fix for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem that I just figured out.  I'm on my work laptop and I had previously installed `just` using MacPorts, since I like it but I didn't want to install a full rust toolchain on this machine as we didn't have any Rust projects yet.  Now a few months later I installed `rustup` and got the warning about there being an outdated preexisting toolchain elsewhere on the machine, which left me super confused because I didn't remember installing it, but I went through with it anyways since I thought I could figure it out.  The other answers didn't work for me since I already had `rust-src` installed, but after trying to run `rustc --print sysroot` and doing a bit of detective work with `zsh -xl` thanks to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from) I realized MacPorts was fighting with the rest of my shell config and overriding `$PATH`.

So the solution for me was removing the old toolchains (and MacPorts entirely), and confirming that my `$PATH` was set up properly.  I still couldn't get rust-analyzer to cooperate afterwards, but running `rustc --print sysroot` and setting `"rust-analyzer.cargo.sysroot": "/path/to/sysroot"` with the output of that command fixed the problem, I just had to restart rust-analyzer afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue in VsCode fixed with :

```
rustup update
rustup component add rust-src
```